# JSON Web Token expiration and remember me functionality

Tags: django, authentication, angular, django-rest-framework, jwt

I am starting to work on an authentication system for an angular 2 Single Page Application using django-rest framework as back-end. I'd also like to have some kind of "remember me" functionality that is going to keep users logged in for a certain amount of time.

From what I have read so far, it seems that the best authentication method for this kind of Angular 2 SPA/REST API is using jwt (json web token). For jwt authentication, I looked at the django-rest-framework-jwt (https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt).

The **problem** that I see is that the token needs to have a short life span (few minutes to a few hours...) in order to minimize security issues if the token get stolen. The token now needs to be refreshed frequently to avoid the user from being disconnected while using the application. In this case, a "remember me" functionality is posing problem since the token have a short life span.

I thought about a **solution** involving a second token that would serve as a refresh token. It would be opaque, have a longer life span and would contain information specific to the user (ip address or something like that) so that if it get stolen, the information specific to the user being different would render this refresh token invalid.

So here are my **questions**:

1- I would like to know if they are existing solutions addressing this problem. As any security/authentication issues, I prefer to rely on well tested solutions to avoid getting my API compromised.
2- Would the refresh token based on specific user infos be a good idea?
3- Any other ideas how I could implement what I want?

Comment: Is the remember me functionality going to optional or for all users without a choice?

Comment: @JJB Eventually, I would like the "remember me" functionality to be optional. But for a first step, for all users would be ok.

Comment: I'm not sure so much about the django-rest-framework-jwt itself, can you choose what data is stored in the JWT? You could have it return 2 different refresh tokens:

REMEMBER ME version if remember me is selected at login you will return a refresh token with a longer expiration also including other data within the JWT like you said IP or even browser fingerprint. You will need a way to revoke the refresh tokens.

NONE REMEMBER ME version refresh token will return a short expiration.

Comment: Session cookies are very much like tokens, but they have built in expiry and  come stock with Django.  You'd probably be better off just using Django sessions instead of tokens.

Comment: @RossRogers I thought about using Django sessions, but I am planning on using the same Rest-API for mobile applications. I haven’t done a lot of research on the subject but it seems that Django sessions won’t work with mobile app. But yes, using sessions would be a good temporary solution to my problem...

Comment: @JJB Yes it is possible to choose what is stored into the JWT. Using some browser info with ip adress would not be unique but I think it should be  specific enough to get some level of protection to the refresh token.  
If the token is encrypted in a way that it is opaque to the client, maybe I could put the user's password in it. If the refresh token needs to be revoked, the user would just have to change his password. Even though this token would be encrypted, I not quite comfortable having the user's credential store on client side...

Comment: @RossRogers sessions don't really work in a real rest API workflow.

Comment: @F.Caron my reply was too large for a comment so I've had to add it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your situation, you really need a way to store issued tokens.

I always use an OAuth2.0 server setup that manages the auth and returns tokens the OAuth setup uses a database to manage everything so it's easy to manage and revoke tokens.

The database schema would be like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOoBf.jpg the problem with using just JWT without any management over the issued tokens with long expiration you have that security issue of not being able to revoke easily.

I would advise against including any such thing as a password in the JWT and requiring them to change it what if they use that password everywhere, then they would have to change that everywhere.

**Updated from comments**

**Sessions Authentication** use session_id which most the time is stored in a cookie and this is attached to every outgoing request. It is stateful. It is nothing more than a unique identifier that associates a user account that the server has in memory/database. For example, this can course problems when running multiple servers/instances when scaling your infrastructure.

**Token Authentication** no session is persisted on the server so this means it is stateless. It normally uses the header Authorization: Bearer REPLACE-WITH-TOKEN . This means that this token can be passed to multiple different servers/instances because the authentication is not limited to the server that you initiated the authentication on. This helps with scaling your infrastructure. Tokens can also be passed to other clients.

RESTful API's are stateless so there must not be a session state stored on the server. Instead, it must the handled entirely by the client so that's why token authentication is used.

I had the exact problem when trying to use JWT with an application that needed a lot more than JWT was designed for. OAuth2.0 has a lot more options that I believe are necessary to meet your requirement in the safest manner possible and even features that you may find very useful in the future as your Application may grow and need more features with regards authentication.

Comment: I have previously looked at the OAuth2 framework. There is a package for django rest for this (<https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit>). But it only use token and not JWT. Would this solution be kind of similar to the session solution proposed by RossRogers in the previous comments? With the difference that the session token is store as a cookie and the OAuth token is stored where we want (local storage or cookie)..?

Comment: Sorry, I misplaced that JWT within the OAuth context it should just say token. I'll update that now and also answer your other questions.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!